# Does php 4.4.8 support mysqli (object-oriented style)?

Tags: mysqli, php4

Does PHP 4.4.8 version support mysqli object-oriented style?  I have made ready this project on PHP5 and when I got online hosting, I came to know that the online version is 4.4.8.

How can I make my mysqli project work on this domain?

Comment: There's only one solution: cancel your contract with that hosting provider **as soon as possible**. First of all, PHP4 is horribly outdated. Besides that, the most recent PHP4 version is 4.4.9 which fixed **security holes** - and it way released **three years ago**. So your hosting provider doesn't seem to care about security AND uses ancient versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), everything below PHP 5.2.17 (inclusively) is not supported any more (read: from PHP's point of view, it's history).

Thus you should urge your hosting company to upgrade. Use this argument. If they don't understand, they're not professional and you should change your hosting.

When you start using PHP 5.3, and if it's not too much effort, switch over to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).

Answer (score 2):

Try writing a mysqli-compliant wrapper around the `mysql_*` functions.
Either that, or refactor your project to either use `mysql_*` your own db library.